# React: TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a React App, and i'm trying to get some data using an [axios](https://axios-http.com) GET request from my node backend.

the Api Endpoint i'm currently using that regard this problem is the following:

```
// NodeJS Backend
app.get('/v1/companys/user/:user_uuid', verify, (req, res) => { // GET - Company by User UUID
    const selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM companys WHERE uuid = (SELECT company_uuid FROM users WHERE uuid = ?)';
    connection.query(selectQuery, [req.params.user_uuid], (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else if (results.length === 0) {
            res.json({status: 404, message: 'Company not found'})
        } else {
            res.json({data: results})
        }
    });
});
```

This is my Front End:

```
// ReactJS FrontEnd
const companyLogo = userCompany ? userCompany.logo_url : null;

  console.log(userCompany);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserCompany = async () => {
      try {
        await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + 'companys/user/' + userUuid).then((response) => {
          console.log("response "+ response);
          let res = response.data.data[0];
          console.log(res);
          setUserCompany(res);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getUserCompany();
  }, [userUuid]);
```

There app works fine, but on the console the following error appear:

The object below the error is in fact the thing that i need (`companyLogo`)

I was wondering if someone know what am I doing wrong on my frontend to fix the TypeError.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Can you log your response.data (and response.data.data)?

Comment: Yes, here is the console.log response, using JSON.stringify()
https://imgur.com/a/GuHBN4S

Comment: It would be important to see that output for the case that failed, not the successful ones... So make sure to put it above the failing line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) to catch possible `null`/`undefined` values, you'll most likely fix the issue.

So like this: `let res = response.data.data?.[0];`